# Unable to build the image using the repo gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker in concourse

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline

This is my task in concourse pipeline, where I'm using the repository gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker to build the image.

But I'm getting below error message,

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? failed

What the repository gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker unable to build the image?

fly version 7.9.1

Please assist on this?

- task: get-commit-id

  config:

  ```
  platform: linux
  image_resource:
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  inputs:
  - name: gke-app
  outputs:
  - name: commit-id
  run:
    path: bash
    args:
    - -c
    - |
      docker build --tag=((repo)):latest .
  ```